# How to find Hide my email or show my email parameter in apple login response

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I attached Screen sort Apple login popup. please help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQD9W.png

Comment: There is no indication as to which option the user chose.

Comment: The point is that you have no control over what the user chooses and if you e.g. treat the user differently based on their choice chances are your app will not be approved

Answer (score 0):

You can not control the user to share his email.

But, when the user chooses to hide his email, apple will send you a `private email` associated with the user instead of the actual email. The private email looks like `askhjdgabskdjh@privaterelay.appleid.com`

Emails sent to the private email will be forwarded to the user's original email (though they may go into the spam folder).